# Area between curves is

Tags: integration, area

The area bounded by the parabolas y^2=4x and y^2=x and the lines x=1 and x=4 is

I had tried this and got my answer as 1. But there is no such option. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I haven't worked the problem, but just ruling out the obvious: did you consider the areas both above and below the $x$-axis?

Comment: If you edit your question to show how you reached an answer of $1$ then we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: No. The areas above and below will be equal and I got each of them as 1. But that's not the answer atleast according to the answer key.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Justify and solve$$S=2\int_1^4\int_{\sqrt x}^{2\sqrt x}dydx$$

Comment: But from where did you get this?

Comment: Try plotting the area and using symmetry.